# How to use session in dependency injection with parent construct?

Tags: magento2.2, coding-standards, meqp2

Below error is showing when I tried to run with MEQP2 sniff.
[image]

**Code:**

```
class History extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config $orderConfig
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config $orderConfig
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $orderCollectionFactory, $customerSession, $orderConfig, $data);
    }
}
```

How to pass session object in to constructor and parent constructor ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

=> You can pass it as an argument by creating a `di.xml` like

**di.xml :**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODULENAME\Block\Order\History">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="customerSession" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\Model\Session</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

*=> And in your class file*

```
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;

class History extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History
{
     /**
      * @var SessionManagerInterface
      */
      protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory
     * @param SessionManagerInterface $customerSession
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config $orderConfig
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
        SessionManagerInterface $customerSession,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config $orderConfig
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $orderCollectionFactory, $customerSession, $orderConfig, $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First use session class then you can pass it into constuctor

```
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;

    class ClassName {
        ...



        public function __construct(
            ....
            CustomerSession $customerSession,
            ....
        ){
            ....
            parent::__construct($context, $orderCollectionFactory, $customerSession, $orderConfig, $data);
            ....
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not resolved, Same error showing

Comment: run setup:upgrade command and try again

Comment: This issue Related with coding standard sniff with MEQP2 not with command :(